# Jquery AJAX PHP data return

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using the ajax function in Jquery to return some values from a PHP script with the json_encode function. The returned data seems to be full of slashes, quotes and \r\n. I understand that there must be something going wrong with stripslashes or magic_quotes (which is turned on) but can't seem to manage to get a clean output

Comment: Any chance you could add some code ? will help a lot in trying to help you

Comment: JSON is full of quotes, and needs plenty of escaping of it's contents, so it may BE clean, just your handling of it is off. JSON.org, and you can validate JSON with tools like jsonlint.com

Answer (score 3):

Make sure on your ajax call from jQuery, you tell it to expect a json response. It sounds like you're returning plaintext and trying to parse it manually.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "myscript.php",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
    console.log( data ); //this line only works with chrome (stock) or FireFox (with FireBug plugin)
  }
});
```

That code will echo in your console (if you don't have chrome or FF with FireBug, go get one of them :P) the json encoded output. Remember when you output from PHP, all you should be doing is this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $myAssociativeArrayOfData );
exit; //make sure nothing else happens to output something
```

You don't need to use any special formatting or slashes. Just make sure the json code gets output as json code with the proper headers and jQuery's ajax function should convert it for you. The result will be the data variable in the success function being your json object (php array). So if you pass in an array like this: array('foo'=>'bar') in PHP, then in your success function in jquery, you could type: alert( data.foo ); and get a dialog box that says "bar".